# How to get output result from stored procedure use Entity Framework in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project; my goal is to prepare a report from a table so, the first time I've wrote Linq code but it was too slow.

And after that I've written a SQL query it was so fast and I want to use stored procedure for getting report data from my table. In fact my project is so easy: it gets two dates - start date and end date - and displays result in a table.

I want to write my stored procedure to get two parameters - start date and end date - from C# code and then return output in a variable in C#.

The first question: how to convert my SQL query to a stored procedure with two parameters, start Date and End date?

The second question: how to return output result in C#?

```
SELECT 
    CAST(date_rec_slash AS DATETIME), COUNT(code_marz) AS total,
    CASE
       WHEN code_marz = 1 THEN 'a'
       WHEN code_marz = 2 THEN 'b'
       WHEN code_marz = 3 THEN 'c'
       WHEN code_marz = 4 THEN 'd'
       WHEN code_marz = 5 THEN 'e'
    END
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_bar 
WHERE 
    CAST(date_rec_slash AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '2017/12/01' AND '2017/12/31'
GROUP BY 
    CAST(date_rec_slash AS DATETIME), code_marz
ORDER BY 
    CAST(date_rec_slash AS DATETIME) ASC;
```

C#:

```
var spResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_bar>("Report");
```

[image]

Comment: you want declare a store procedure and call it from C#?

Comment: @HasanFathi,Yes ,in fact you should declare two parameter start date and end date in store preocedure and also I need a output result from store procedure because I have to show output on html table.

Comment: your output is this two variable :SELECT Cast(date_rec_slash as datetime), count(code_marz) as total

Comment: data etime and total

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare your store procedure using this syntax:

```
    USE yourDataBaseNAme
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].yourStoreProcedureName
    @startDate nvarchar(30), 
    @endDate   nvarchar(30)
    AS 
       SELECT Cast(date_rec_slash as datetime) AS 'date_rec_slash', count(code_marz) as total,
              CASE
                  WHEN code_marz = 1 THEN 'a'
                  WHEN code_marz = 2 THEN 'b'
                  WHEN code_marz = 3 THEN 'c'
                  WHEN code_marz = 4 THEN 'd'
                  WHEN code_marz = 5 THEN 'e'
              END AS 'code_marz'
      FROM dbo.tbl_bar 
     WHERE Cast(date_rec_slash as datetime) between @startDate 
                                                AND @endDate
     GROUP BY Cast(date_rec_slash as datetime), code_marz
     ORDER BY Cast(date_rec_slash as datetime) ASC;
    GO
```

Call this store procedure in EF:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<yourObjectNameToCAST>("yourStoreProcedureName");
```

Call store procedure with parameter in EF:

```
SqlParameter startDate= new SqlParameter("@startDate", "Value");
SqlParameter endDate= new SqlParameter("@endDate", "Value");
db.Database.SqlQuery<yourObjectNameToCAST>("exec yourStoreProcedureName @startDate, @endDate", startDate, endDate).ToList();
```

your Object to Cast:

```
public class yourObjectNameToCAST
{
     public datetime date_rec_slash { get; set; }
     public int total { get; set; }
     public string code_marz { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @behnam this is helpful for you?

Comment: How to pass two parameter from EF SqlQuery db.Database.SqlQuery<yourObjectNameToCAST>("yourStoreProcedureName",paramas);

Comment: but there is a little bit issue about it.it was return 246 records but all of them are null value.In fact I need just the same output of sql server.https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500535291910

Comment: i have not any idea from your data

Comment: probably your issue about null values related your given data casting, please check your  field name equal to names that receive from database

Comment: I just need three outputs datetime and total and name of them forexample a,b,c,d,e that's all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164032/discussion-between-hasan-fathi-and-behnam-farhadi).

Comment: @benam please check final change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164062/discussion-between-behnam-farhadi-and-hasan-fathi).

Answer (score 4):

You can declare your stored procedures using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].YourStoredProcedure
    @Start DATETIME, 
    @END   DATETIME
AS
```

Then you can get rid of the code needed to cast from string

In order to get the results mapped as a c# object, you need to use `SqlQuery` or `FromSql` depending on the version of Entity Framework that you are using

**Entity Framework 6**

```
var result = dbContext.Bar.SqlQuery("EXEC YourStoredProcedure").ToList();
```

To pass a parameter, you woild do something like

```
var result = dbContext.Bar.SqlQuery("EXEC YourStoredProcedure @SomeParameter", 
             new SqlParameter("@SomeParameter", TheParameterValue)).ToList();
```

**And for Entity Framework Core 2**

```
var result = dbContext.Bar
.FromSql("EXEC YourStoredProcedure")
.ToList();
```

Where `Bar` is your C# object declared as a  property with type `DbSet<Bar>` in your dbContext class

Based on your output you should create a C# object similar to

```
public class Bar
{
     public datetime DateRecSlash { get; set; }
     public int CodeMarz { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but didn't exist FromSql Method I'm using EF 6.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm using the latest version of EF. Will update my answer for the solutions for both versions