# How to call stored procedure with input parameter and fill textbox with output parameter?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm createing a simple ASP.NET MVC web app. I'm trying to call my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetMesData]
    @WONo varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        [Resname],
        [SAP_ARTIKELNUMMER],
        [LotNo]
    FROM 
        dbo.vw_MES
    WHERE 
        WONo = @WONo
END
```

My model:

```
namespace SlurryOrderTest.Models
{
    public class UserResponse
    {
        [Required]
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string MatNumber { get; set; }
        public string SlurryNumber { get; set; }
        public string BatchNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my controller I'm trying to call stored procedure with input parameter from first TextBox ("send") from view but I don't know how to fill other three textboxes with output parameters from my stored procedure.

```
namespace SlurryOrderTest.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        SlurryOrderTest.Models.SlurryOrderEntities1 db = 
            new SlurryOrderTest.Models.SlurryOrderEntities1();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string send)
        {
            var mesdata = db.sp_GetMesData(send);
            //What i should add here?
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
   {
       @Html.TextBox("send")
       <input type="submit" value="Send" />
   }

@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
   //That also need changes
   <p>Mat number:<br>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MatNumber)</p>
   <p>Slurry number:<br>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SlurryNumber)</p>
   <p>Batch number:<br>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BatchNumber)</p>
```

Comment: check bellow answer @kwiecmac

Comment: Does it ever get into the method `Index` with the parameter?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. I'll remeber this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define model in your view :

```
@model UserResponse
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
       {
           @Html.TextBox("send")
           <input type="submit" value="Send" />
       }
....
```

and pass model with ActionResult in Controller:

```
....
var mesdata = db.sp_GetMesData(send);
return View(mesdata);
....
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution doesn't work. Probably it's ma fault because when i click on my TextBox "Send" i have a message: "The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations"

Comment: your view must named "Index" or your Action Name must be changes. in other hand your view name and your action name must be same. or must use view name in action result like this: return View("ViewName",model) @KwiecMac

Comment: You have right - i changed it. But now when I click button "Send" i have a message: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[SlurryOrderTest.Models.sp_GetMesData_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SlurryOrderTest.Models.UserResponse'."

Comment: your sp result type must of type : UserResponse. you must cast sp results to an object of type UserResponse

Comment: I tried to do this but without a positive result :( Can you give me more tips? Sorry for my stupid questions but i'm beginner with C# and ASP.NET MVC

Comment: this link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483715/how-to-get-output-result-from-stored-procedure-use-entity-framework-in-c/48483812

Comment: I cast sp results and now i have another problem with my procedure or with your solution. Another error: "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SlurryOrderModel.sp_GetMesData_Result'. A member of the type, 'WONo', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Comment: sp result columns and class properties must be same in name and type. check WONo column exists in both and type of both is same.