# EF6 shows different results from stored procedure than when executed manually

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ssms

I'm using a local SQL Server Express database with Windows authentication.

I have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp-report-HoursPerWeek]
    @year int,
    @user nvarchar(75)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT 
        DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, H.[From]) weekn, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, H.[From], H.Until)) 
    FROM HourLines H
    INNER JOIN Users U ON H.User_UserId = U.UserId
    WHERE U.EmailAddress = @user
      AND H.HourlineStatus_HourlineStatusId != 5
      AND ((DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, H.[From]) = 53 
            AND DATEPART (MONTH, H.[From]) = 12 
            AND DATEPART (YEAR, H.[From]) = @year)
           OR
           (DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, H.[From]) = 53 
            AND DATEPART (MONTH, H.[From]) = 1 
            AND DATEPART (YEAR, H.[From]) = @year +1)
           OR
           (DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, H.[From]) != 53 
            AND DATEPART (YEAR, H.[From]) = @year)
          )
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART (ISO_WEEK, H.[From])
    ORDER BY 
        weekn
GO
```

When I run this in SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp-report-HoursPerWeek] @year = 2020, @user = 'qlkjasd@lksjadlak.com'
```

I get these results:

```
 1. 33  480
 2. 34  540
 3. 35  480
 4. 36  1560
 5. 37  900
 6. 40  960
 7. 41  1320
```

But when I execute it from my code, using Entity Framework 6, I get something different. The same 7 rows, but this time, each row has 0 0.

[image: Debugging EF result]

As you can see in the screenshot, I added a trace for EF. Didn't help much. This is what it said:

```
Opened connection at 7-10-2020 20:55:10 +02:00

[dbo].[sp-report-HoursPerWeek] @year, @user


-- @year: '2020' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- @user: 'qlkjasd@lksjadlak.com' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 18)

-- Executing at 7-10-2020 20:55:10 +02:00

-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader



Closed connection at 7-10-2020 20:55:10 +02:00
```

I've been googling, but you can imagine I was only able to come up with some very generic search terms, like "ef6 producing different results than management studio", which yielded nothing.

Does anyone know what I'm overlooking?

Comment: We'll need to see a [mcve]. It seems _incredibly_ likely that your column names returned by your SQL don't match the property names in your C# class. You also forgot to give an alias to `SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, H.[From], H.Until))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get output result from stored procedure use Entity Framework in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483715/how-to-get-output-result-from-stored-procedure-use-entity-framework-in-c)

Comment: @mjwills That was exactly it. I'm embarrassed I didn't realize the aliases had to line up with the property names. It makes total sense, but I would never have come up with that on my own. Thank you!

If you wish you can post the answer. The propery names are visible in the screenshot if you wish to reference that. I can also edit the question and provide the c# class the result is represented by.

Comment: Have a great day!

Comment: @mjwills And you :)

Edited last comment by the way.